# how to aggregate case-class in scala gracefully?

Tags: scala

```
case class value(x1:Long, x2: Double, ..., xk: Long, ... ,xn:Int) {

  def add(rValue: Value): Value = {
   Value(
     x1 = x1 + rValue.x1,
     ...
     xk = xk + rValue.xk,
     ...
     xn = xn + rvalu.xn
   )
 }

}
```

I want to aggregate case-class('value'), I think this manual implementation is not elegant when n is large (such as n = 500?)

Comment: all fields is numeric

Comment: The best approach would be to just do it manually (not mutating, in your case you're doing `x1 = x1 + ...`, avoid this, return new instance instead). There are some fancy ways like reflection and maybe some few other things, but they're all discouraged and reduce the readability. So I recommend `Value(x1 = x1 + other.x1, ...)` (If I understood your question correctly)

Comment: @AminMal tanks，i'm sorry that my code is error. It's `Value(x1 = x1 + rValue.x1, ..., xn = xn + rvalu.xn)`. I think this manual implementation is not elegant when n is large (such as n = 500?)

Comment: A class with 500 fields?! If yes, I think you should change your modeling, using Map[String, Int] (or numeric) would be a better modeling rather than having such large class with fields x1, …, xn.

Comment: But if you still insist on using a super large class, there are some unsafe workarounds, take a loot at reflection.

Comment: Check out https://www.scala-exercises.org/shapeless/auto_typeclass_derivation

Comment: Is it a contrived example of what you want to achieve or do you really need a class with 500 fields? I would suggest its not a good idea to have a class with 500 fields; use `Seq` or any of its subtypes

Comment: It is unclear what the actual question is here. Are you asking what to do instead of this abomination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution works in Scala3 with build-in api only:

```
trait Add[N] { def add(x: N, y: N): N }

object Add:
  import scala.deriving.Mirror.ProductOf
  
  given Add[Int]        = _ + _
  given Add[Long]       = _ + _
  given Add[Float]      = _ + _
  given Add[Double]     = _ + _
  given Add[EmptyTuple] = (_, _) => EmptyTuple
  given [H, T <: Tuple](using ha: Add[H], ta: Add[T]): Add[H *: T] = 
    case (hx*:tx, hy*:ty) => ha.add(hx, hy) *: ta.add(tx, ty)
  given [P <: Product](using p: ProductOf[P], a: Add[p.MirroredElemTypes]): Add[P] = 
    (x, y) => p.fromProduct(a.add(Tuple.fromProductTyped(x), Tuple.fromProductTyped(y)))
```

Then we can define `Value` class as:

```
scala> case class Value(x1: Int, x2: Float, x3: Double):
     |   def add(that: Value): Value = summon[Add[Value]].add(this, that)
     |

scala> Value(1, 2, 3).add(Value(3, 4, 5))
val res0: Value = Value(4,6.0,8.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fields in case classes are [immutable](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html), return a new instance with all the updated fields.

```scala
case class Value(x: Int, y: Int) { 
  def + (other: Value): Value =
    Value(x + other.x, y + other.y)
}

Value(10, 20) + Value(10, 20)
//res0: Value = Value(20,40)

Value(10, 20) + Value(20, 30) + Value(30, 50)
//res1: Value = Value(60,100)
```

Comment: That's already what OP is doing and doesn't answer its question